# Account history from latest to oldest (position, offset) for pagination

Tags: cleos

The code to get the latest 20 history action by user is

```
get actions <account_name> -1 -20
```

But I am having problem of retrieving it by 5 items only. I want to achieve to get transaction for pagination 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20.

Getting the first 5 latest actions is

```
get actions <account_name> -1 -5
```

But when I tried

```
get actions <account_name> -6 -10
```

to get the next 6-10 items, the results are empty.

Anybody knows what is the correct command ?

Comment: hello, do you use history plugins?

Comment: yes, it requires history plugin to pull account actions

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible using [the current implementation](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/plugins/history_plugin/history_plugin.cpp#L314-L381). At the moment, it seems like `pos == -1` [is a special case](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/plugins/history_plugin/history_plugin.cpp#L328) where actions are displayed up to the most recent ones, while it usually expects positive `pos` to retreive the actions within a range i.e. `[pos, pos+offset]` or `[pos-offset, pos)`.

So perhaps you can try positive ranges because `$ cleos get actions eosio -1 -1` will show you the index of the latest action so you can set your ranges from there; e.g.

```
$ cleos get actions eosio 10094963 10
$ cleos get actions eosio 10094953 10
...
$ cleos get actions eosio 0 10
```

Comment: `$ cleos get actions eosio -1 -1` will show you the index of the latest action so you can set your ranges from there. I guess this line should be highlighted.